# Alternative to Cronjob using AWS Lambda + Cloudwatch ()

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm a developer on a startup and right now we are using around 30 cronjobs, some of them run each minute, others run once per day while other run on specific days. The problem are the ones that run every minute, when most of the time is not necessary.

This somewhat increases our expenses because during the night, they still run when most of the times our services have nobody online (and don't require to be run).

We have been talking about using AWS to replace those cronjobs into something like event based. Yet, I cannot find a solution. Here's an example of one of our cronjobs:

- One costumer starts to make a registration and has 8 minutes to complete it. Right now, we have a cronjob that runs every minute to validate if he completed, and if not, to "delete" it.

I though I could replace this with a SNS + Lambda event. Basically, when an user starts registration, send an message to SNS, that would triger a lambda function. Yet, it could only run after 8 minutes, and not instantly.

I've seen on SNS that we can delay up to 15 minutes, but we got some other service that sends an email after few hours, which would not work

Anyone have a clue on how can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AWS step functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) to implement the workflow and add a [delay to wait](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-wait-state.html) before invoking the Lambda function.